# Content search related to feature

Tags: helix

I am working on Helix based project.
I've already implemented Foundation.Indexing project and also I've implemented news search and blog search based on Foundation.Indexing. Now I am working on site content search. I have a small specific in this easy functionality. I need to render search result text depend on item result template.

something like

```
if (itemResult.TemplateId == NewsTemplateId) 
{ then render "Hello this is news" }
else if (itemResult.TemplateId == BlogTemplateId)
{ then render "Hello this is blog" }
else 
{ render item["BodyText"] }
```

Following Helix principles: references between features are not allowed.

How I can handle without breaking the principles?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are breaking a more important principle of not hard-coding stuff.

It can be easily fixed by adding a new template called i.e. **SearchPreviewable** with the field **Preview Text** and inherit your news/blog/etc templates from the **SearchPreviewable** template.

Then you will only need to do something like this in your code:

```
 render item["Preview Text"]
```

Without any template comparison needed.

In case you still want to use the "**BodyText**" in some cases, you should leave only one comparison statement:

```
if (itemResult.TemplateId == SearchPreviewableTemplateId) 
{ then render item["Preview Text"] }
else 
{ render item["BodyText"] }
```

Comment: Where I should put SearchPreviewable template? should it be feature or foundation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with having your Template references in the Foundation Indexing or Foundation Search project. That way your Feature project is not referencing other Feature projects.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either build this search functionality at the project level, thus being able to see all the feature templates. Or you can move the field you want to search, like Title or Abstract, to the foundation level and search on those fields.

I have searchable fields in a new Foundation.Taxonomy project and then filter my pages on that taxonomy fields.

Answer (score 0):

My hot take is that cross-project item ID violations aren't a big deal. In practice, I have never seen it be a significant enough problem to make me think, "I wish I didn't do it this way". It depends on how complex and large your solution is. While following Helix is generally a good idea, it is up to you to weigh the costs and benefits of individual violations.

That said, there are many approaches to complying with Helix. One of them is to consolidate some of your feature projects, where it makes sense.

Another is to store commonly used template IDs in a common location.

The galaxy brain solution is to incorporate strategic use of base templates along with design patterns such as:

- Dependency injection
- Repositories
- Services
- Providers

Imagine a scenario where you have a computed field for item "Title" in a Foundation-level project. Each of your features may have different logic for determining what an item title should be, so:

1. Create a `Foundation.ITitleRepository` interface that defines `string? GetTitle(Item item);`
2. Implementat a `Foundation.IItemDataRepository`:

```csharp
namespace Website.Foundation.Repositories
{
    public class ItemDataRepository : IItemDataRepository
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ITitleRepository> _titleRepositories;

        public ItemDataRepository(
            IEnumerable<ITitleRepository> titleRepositories)
        {
            _titleRepositories = titleRepositories;
        }
        
        public string? GetTitle(Item item)
        {
            if (item.DescendsFrom(SOME_COMMON_ID))
            {
                // return the field value
            }

            foreach (ITitleRepository provider in _titleRepositories)
            {
                string? title = provider.GetTitle(item);
                if (title != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
                {
                    return title;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Implement the computed field as follows:

```csharp
namespace Website.Foundation.Indexing
{
    public class TitleComputedField
    {
        private readonly IItemDataRepository _itemDataRepository;

        public TitleComputedField() : this(Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IItemDataRepository>())
        {

        }

        public TitleComputedField(IItemDataRepository itemDataRepository)
        {
            _itemDataRepository = itemDataRepository;
        }

        protected override object? ComputeFieldValue(Item item)
        {
            return _itemDataRepository.GetTitle(item);
        }
    }
}
```

4. In each Feature, create an implementation of the `ITitleRepository` wherever you need this functionality.

There are some details I am leaving out, but once you begin to grasp these concepts, the possibilities really open up.